# export image (jpg png pdf) from netlogo

Tags: image, export, jpeg, netlogo

I'm currently working on a project, I would like to ask how to export images from Netlogo? 
My idea is to have a "button" in the interface to export image (JPG, PNG, or PDF) from the Netlogo "world" box. Is it possible? Can I use the bitmap extension for this? or export-view?

Comment: I believe `export-view` is what you're looking for

Comment: Hi thank you for answering. I have solved this issue. But I have another one, is there a way to edit the file name every time I want to save the file?

Comment: Please open a new question.

Comment: Hi Seth, I have opened a new question. I hope you could help me with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796314/editing-file-name-when-using-export-view-in-netlogo

Answer (score 1):

The `export-view` primitive does exactly this. See https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#export-cmds