# Editing file name when using export-view in Netlogo

Tags: view, save, export, netlogo

I want to use export-view to save an image of my model. I have made a button in the interface to export image (JPG, PNG, or PDF) from the Netlogo.

this is my current code in the export-view button

```
file-open user-new-file
export-view (word "view1.jpg")
set view-number view-number + 1
```

Currently, file-open command helps in showing a pop-up input window before saving. There is a runtime error of "FILE-OPEN expected input to be a string but got the TRUE/FALSE false instead". I can still save the file but this pop's up from time to time

At first try the I can save the files successively.  Now, it only saves one file named view1 everytime. Is there something wrong with new code?

Comment: (1) Please check what the tag is for before adding it. (2) Do you mean edit the file name interactively, or do you want user input for the file name or something else?

Comment: Noted on the first item, sorry I'm quite new to stack overflow. My idea is to have a pop-up input window where I can change the file name before it will be saved.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `user-new-file` primitive in the NetLogo dictionary. That allows you to get the user input and then you can use the `word` primitive to save in the same way that you are doing it now.

The short version of complete code is:

```
to testme1
  export-view user-new-file
end
```

To get a full idea of what's going on, here's a longer version:

```
to testme2
  let fn user-new-file
  print fn
  set fn word fn ".png"
  print fn
  if file-exists? fn [file-delete fn]
  file-open fn
  export-view fn
  file-close
end
```

So what actually happens is the `user-new-file` returns a string for whatever the user enters. You can use that string directly with the `export-view`, or you can manipulate it a bit and then use it. I'm not completely clear why you are getting that particular error, but the code you have is creating/opening a file with a different name than the name you try and export to.

For example, in my testme2 code, I appended the 'png' extension on the assumption that the user did not type this. In a real application, you could look at the last 3 characters and add the extension only if required for example. My longer code also deletes any existing file of that name - I don't think this is required for png views as I think NetLogo simply overwrites, but exporting to csv would add lines at the end.

Comment: Hi JenB, I applied 'filename-user-new-file' to my model. A "pop-up" window does come out. It does save a file but I still can't change the filename. So I decided to combine your suggestion and Charles'.

Comment: I just encountered a runtime error of "FILE-OPEN expected input to be a string but got the TRUE/FALSE false instead". I can still save the file but this pop's up from time to time

Comment: see my revised answer

Comment: Hi JenB, thank you for the revision. Your answer is on point with my question. and also, the longer version works better for me.

Answer (score 1):

JenB's answer may be exactly what you are looking for. But to cover another possibility suggested by your original filename, you may be looking to number multiple export files, perhaps exported every few ticks or when something interesting occurs, or as you have it, whenever the `export-view` button is pressed. In that case, if you define a global variable such as `view-number`, you could then use the code

```
export-view (word "view" view-number ".jpg")
set view-number view-number + 1
```

This will give you successive files "view0.jpg", "view1.jpg", "view2.jpg" ...  `view-number` is initialized at 0, but you could start with some other number if you wish.

Comment: Hi Charles, your answer helps complete the code. I can just click my export-view button and it saves it successively.